# in BeforeClass method how to insert init data to db

Tags: spring-test

I have a `UserServiceTest`, I want to init load some user data to database for tests e.g. queryByName, groupByAge and so on . And I want to only load once in this class, so I want to use BeforeClass

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init(){
    // ...
}
```

but in this case I find I cannot use `jdbcTemplate` to insert data just like in `Before` e.g.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    // prepare test data first        
    jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into user(firstname,lastname,birthday) values(...);");
}
```

So in `BeforeClass` method how to insert init data?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `TestExecutionListeners` in order to initialise your database before test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, listeners = {
        DbInitializerTestListener.class })
public class DbTest {

}


public class DbInitializerTestListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                .autowireBean(this);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into user(firstname,lastname,birthday) values(...);");

    }
}
```

Or you may consider [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) framework.